# How to draw a transition system in promela?

Tags: promela, transition-systems

I am new to promela. I have a programming which is written in promela:

```
bit signal [2];
active [2] proctype proc() {
l1: signal[_pid]=1;
l2: !signal[1-_pid] -> 
l3: signal[_pid]=0;
}
#define sig0 (signal[0]==0)
#define sig1 (signal[0]==1)
```

Does anybody know how to draw transition system for this program?

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute all possible interleavings of your promela model. In your case there are two active processes, so this still be doable; however, you still get a picture with 20 nodes. To get some inspiration, I would suggest to apply the `spinspider` tool:

```
spinspider -p2 -vsignal[0] -vsignal[1] yourProgram.pml
```

The result is the following image: [Transition System](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0I86uCkoD8MUzZHbTg5U3U2RlE/edit?usp=sharing)

`spinspider` is part of the [JSpin distribution](http://code.google.com/p/jspin/), which should be still usable although JSpin is deprecated by now.